# Ruby: overwriting an alias

Tags: ruby

```
def a_method
  p "in distress"
end

alias :hero :a_method
def a_method
  hero
  p "Saved by the hero"
end
```

Here is a method in distress and it has been saved by a hero. But someone else doesn't like how the story ends and decides to overwrite what the hero did.

```
alias :nemesis ?
def ?
   #which method to call?
   p "Captured by the nemesis"
end
```

Is it possible for the nemesis to overwrite what the hero did and have the final outcome be

```
"in distress"
"Captured by the nemesis"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this would work without any more aliasing:

```
def a_method
  hero
  p "Captured by the nemesis"
end
```

There isn't any way for the nemesis to "unalias" and determine the old value of :a_method before the hero came along, however.  The fact that Ruby doesn't preserve history like that is the reason you need aliases in such override situations in the first place.

Comment: From my understanding of how alias works, calling `hero` now is basically the same as calling the original method. Is there a situation where `hero` has modified the data in the original method that I can no longer get?

Comment: Ruby is completely dynamic; it's entirely possible to alter a method at any time, or remove it completely, and even use runtime values to redefine it. So any situation you can imagine is probably *possible*...